# Passing paramiter values to three.js via vars (or php echo) causes undesired results

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, three.js, var

When I pass the values to three.js like so..

```
const paintgeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(2.5, 1.5, 3.3, 240, 1, true);
```

The result looks like this (all is as expected)..

[image]

However if i pass the same as a var like so..

```
var trad = '2.5';
const paintgeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(trad, 1.5, 3.3, 240, 1, true);
```

I get very weird 'pinch' or 'hourglass' type results like this..

[image]

I have also tried passing the params as a php echo but get the same odd result?
How can I pass these numbers to the script and not have to hard code them in please?

I have also put the complete code on JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/StickerMonkey/ov12fh3s/53/

Comment: `var trad = '2.5';` must be a number, not a string

Comment: Would  parseInt('2.5') be the correct way forward?

Comment: No, `parseFloat(trad)` is the way